# How to wrap lines of code in Rstudio IDE?

Tags: rstudio, word-wrap

Is there a feature to wrap code in the code window of [RStudio IDE](https://posit.co/products/open-source/rstudio/)?  Note I am not talking about programming, but rather working with the software called RStudio (IDE).

I have a pretty long line of comments, so yes, I can split them into two lines, but it doesn't respect the actual size of the window so if the code is displayed on another computer it may still go beyond the visible part.

So I have looked into the options of Rstudio and browsed the internet, but nothing came to be a solution to this problem.

Comment: Tips. Refer to the official help resources that you have reviewed, you might also show the gui elements that you have reviewed and why didn't meet your needs.

Comment: @Rubén. I am not talking about programming. I am talking about using the software. The software is called [Rstudio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RStudio), I thought, there is just one version of that software, so I clarify it in the post. IDEs are not the applications? At least Rstudio looks like an application. I don't understand what you mean by "GUI elements" in this case.

Comment: Friend, RStudio is a development IDE. While IDEs are applications, they're pretty specific, and you're asking about ... dunno, soft wrapping comment lines? It's a bit unclear. However I'd suggest putting this into what's probably the best known of all SE sites - [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). That's the developer hangout. If you do, please delete this as cross-posting is frowned upon.

Comment: By gui elements I mean the toolbar and toolbar options, contextual menu, command palette, anything that shows you a command, input field or message. What is the operative system that you are using?

Comment: See [Finding hard to fit into right site between Super User and Web Applications](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14924/152004)

Comment: @Juandev RStudio is not a web application. It is a stand-alone application for programming in R. SuperUser is the correct place to post this. _Maybe_ StackOverflow is better for this since it is a programming tool, but I personally think this is fine on SuperUser.

Comment: @Juandev Yesterday I updated my answer. Now I removed the following because it's meta commentary: If you still need help, edit your question to show what you have tried, show what you find (i.e. add some screenshots, you could mention the links mentioned here or others) and why they didn't help you.

Comment: Please let me know if you have seeing my answer, if you find it helpful or if there is something that you need to clarified.

Answer (score 1):

Let me start with the specific issue that you are asking

Searching `rstudio Soft-wrap R source files`

Google returned to me a featured snippet showing

> Soft-wrap R source files — Wrap lines of R source code which exceed the width of the editor onto the next line. Note that this does not insert a line-break at the point of wrapping, it simply displays the code on multiple lines in the editor. Dec 6, 2022
>
> [Customizing the RStudio IDE - Posit Support](https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/200549016-Customizing-the-RStudio-IDE#:%7E:text=Soft%2Dwrap%20R%20source%20files,multiple%20lines%20in%20the%20editor).

I learned the terms to used from [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48746023/1595451) to [wrap code in R Studio text editor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39901028/1595451) ([revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48746023/2) from November 27, 2018)

> "[4. Enable code wrapping](https://impaulchung.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/r-studio-pauls-tips-tricks/)
> If, like me, you like to work with multiple windows up at once, you will undoubtedly run into the issue of not being able to see your code without scrolling sideways. While the best solution is to simply get in the habit of chopping your code up into shorter, more legible segment, a fair alternative is to have R Studio “soft wrap” it for you. All this means is that any part of your R script that would usually fall off the side of your screen is, instead, continued on the following line. Give it a try:"
>
> [image]

The above was found typing `rstudio wrap` in the Chrome address bar, signed in my Google account that is linked to my Stack Exchange accounts.

As you can see in the below screenshot, it is the first result. This worked this way for me due to the personalized results. *Your mileage might vary* (this means that the user experience might be different for each person).

[image]

While nowadays Google suggest to write questions, I suggest the old way, start searching using the minimal simple  keywords.

In this case, the first result is very unlikely that you will be seing the same user interface but the answer show in the screenshot in shown in the Stack Overflow answer, that was actually a quote from a post published on January 9, 2013. I think that it should be good enough to give you an idea about how to explore the RStudio user interface and the wording used on it that might be helpful to refine your following searches.

The next thing that I suggest that you do is to look at the RStudio user interface carefully to try to find the *soft wrapping* feature, if you can't do it follow the link at the top.

Comment: "it's pertinent to include guidance to the OP to improve their question" - This does not belong in an answer on Super User.  If the author of the question, needs to improve their question, in order to answer the question then the question shouldn't be answered until that happens and you should leave a comment indicating the question should be improved..

Comment: @Ramhound Because of that I had delete the answer and posted in meta. Anyway, yesterday I replaced the previous revision with the last revision from meta. The text that you comment is no longer included.